# ASP.net - "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if I might be able to get some assistance as have hit an error with some code I am working on!

When clicking my login button I get the following at Line 37:
"No value given for one or more required parameters.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters."

Any ideas?

Help gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Jack! :)

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CameraWarehouseDB"].ConnectionString);
        //Opens connection with database
        conn.Open();

        //Declared a string - checks to see if username already exisits in the database.
        string checkusername = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [Customer] WHERE CustomerUserName= '" + txtUserName.Text + "'";

        //If count is 1, it means its already exisits, so cannot be used again and triggers alert
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(checkusername, conn);
        //Replace removes any spaces the user make have accidentally inputed in the text box
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            //Verying username and password - Checks for password in database based on entered username
            conn.Open();
            string checkpassword = "SELECT Password FROM [Customer] WHERE CustomerUserName= '" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
            OleDbCommand passwordcom = new OleDbCommand(checkpassword, conn);
            string password = passwordcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            //Verify password based on entered password in password text box
            if (password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"]=txtUserName.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Incorrect password entered, please try again");
            }
        }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Incorrect user name entered, please try again");
            }
        conn.Close();
        }    
}
```

Comment: Line 37 correspond to which line in your code sample?

Comment: Sorry jpgrassi! It's this line "string password = passwordcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();"

Comment: Does temp has any value? If it passed the first query, then the problem is the second query.

Comment: Also, you should not give this kind of error messages to the user. Saying that the password is incorrect opens a huge security breach allowing attackers to know that at least a user exists, narrowing their focus on the password.

Comment: Hello again - Thanks for the reply. I might be going about this the wrong way as I am not that good at coding. Basically its a login page so when the button is clicked after a username/password has been entered, I want it to check the database the see if the username/password match the record and then take them to the homepage if it does or show an error if not. I removed the second query, and the first one works, but not sure what the issue is with the second one. Maybe temp==1 is wrong?

Comment: D'oh! Just noticed I typed one of my table field names incorrectly in the query - not a very clever thing to do!!!! Interested to hear your comments on the above code though - is it better to remove the individual statements and just saying Incorrect password/username combination or something like that then?

Comment: Well I think you should read more about some security concerns regarding passing passwords, returning messages in login actions and also, about SQL injection. Executing your query, a malicious user could inject an script or sql query into your txtUserName.Text and you'll run this against your db. Regarding your code flow, I would only check the username and password in on query. If returns 1 row, the username and password matches. If not, return a generic message: "Username or password not valid".